# How to subtract 60 seconds from current time and display it in "hour:minute:second" format?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to subtract 60 seconds from the current time using the `datetime` module in Python. However, I'm getting the full date including year, month, and milliseconds. I just need it to display the hour, minute, and second. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
currenttime=datetime.datetime.now().strftime(" %H:%M:%S")
print(currenttime)
X = 65
endtime=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(seconds=X)

print(endtime)
```

Comment: You have everything in your code: getting the current time, subtracting a `timedelta` and formatting a `datetime` for output. You just need to put it together in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

To print only the hour, minute and second:

```
print(endtime.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much on the right track. Just format the `endtime`

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

endtime = (datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=60)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost works -- it's just that you forgot to apply `strftime` to your end time.

Also, in your code block as of now, you have `X=65` whereas it should be `X = 60`

**Here is a working version of your code:**

```
currenttime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(currenttime)
X = 60
endtime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=X)

print(endtime.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

That said, I think the code could be made **simpler and more concise like this**:

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
print(start.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

end = start - datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)
print(end.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```